# Enable xp_cmdshell does not work

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, xp-cmdshell

I try to enable `xp_cmdshell` in SQL Server. So I ran:

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
RECONFIGURE
EXEC master.dbo.sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1
RECONFIGURE
```

The returned message says:

> Configuration option 'show advanced options' changed from 1 to 1. Run the RECONFIGURE statement to install.
>
> Configuration option 'xp_cmdshell' changed from 0 to 1. Run the RECONFIGURE statement to install.

The facet properties shows "XPCmdShellEnabled"

However, when I execute

```
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'dir c:'
```

I got the error message

> Msg 15281, Level 16, State 1, Procedure xp_cmdshell, Line 1
>   SQL Server blocked access to procedure 'sys.xp_cmdshell' of component 'xp_cmdshell' because this component is turned off as part of the security configuration for this server. A system administrator can enable the use of 'xp_cmdshell' by using sp_configure. For more information about enabling 'xp_cmdshell', see "Surface Area Configuration" in SQL Server Books Online.

What I did is from Microsoft documentation. Why does it not work?

Comment: What version and edition of SQL Server are you using? It looks like you did it right, and I can't see any reason for it not to work.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. It's SQL Server 2008 R2. Is there any permission require to execute xp_cmdshell?

Comment: SQL Server security isn't my strong side, but I think you need the `CONTROL SERVER` permission. It should be granted to _sa_ and administrators by default.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Lets try this:  Disable it, then re-enbable it.

```
--Disable
Use Master

GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 0
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE

GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_configure 'show advanced options', 0
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
GO

-- Enable
Use Master
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
GO
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this from SQL Server Management Studio as follows:

1. Right-click the server, and choose `Facets`
2. Select Facet `Surface Area Configuration`
3. Set property `XPCmdShellEnabled` to `True`

---

[image]